# Google cloud function integration testing pass param?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, integration-testing

I have created a cloud function to print greetings like "Hello David!". my function below:

```java
public void service(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
        throws IOException {
        String name = request.getFirstQueryParameter("name").orElse("world");
        try {
            JsonElement requestParsed = gson.fromJson(request.getReader(), JsonElement.class);
            JsonObject requestJson = null;

            if (requestParsed != null && requestParsed.isJsonObject()) {
                requestJson = requestParsed.getAsJsonObject();
            }

            if (requestJson != null && requestJson.has("name")) {
                name = requestJson.get("name").getAsString();
            }
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            logger.severe("Error parsing JSON: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        var writer = new PrintWriter(response.getWriter());
        writer.printf("Hello %s!", name);
    }
```

I have written a integration test like below:

```java
  @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        String baseDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        emulatorProcess = new ProcessBuilder()
            .command("./../gradlew", "alo")
            .directory(new File(baseDir))
            .start();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() throws IOException {
        InputStream stdoutStream = emulatorProcess.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stdoutBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        stdoutBytes.write(stdoutStream.readNBytes(stdoutStream.available()));
        System.out.println(stdoutBytes.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        if (emulatorProcess.isAlive()) {
            emulatorProcess.destroy();
        }
    }

    @Test
     void helloHttp_shouldRunWithFunctionsFramework() throws Throwable {
        String functionUrl = BASE_URL + "/helloHttp";
        HttpRequest getRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(functionUrl)).GET().build();

        RetryRegistry registry = RetryRegistry.of(RetryConfig.custom()
            .maxAttempts(6)
            .intervalFunction(IntervalFunction.ofExponentialBackoff(200, 2))
            .retryExceptions(IOException.class)
            .retryOnResult(body -> body.toString().length() == 0)
            .build());
        Retry retry = registry.retry("my");

        String body = Retry.decorateCheckedSupplier(retry, () -> client.send(
            getRequest,
            HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).body()
        ).apply();
        assertThat(body).isEqualTo("Hello world!");
    }
```

So I want to fake a params `name` in the integration test to pass to my GCP function.
so in my GCP function I can take it like this:  `name = requestJson.get("name").getAsString();`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I just search it out and the answer is: add post method like this

```java
  HttpRequest getRequest = HttpRequest
            .newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create(functionUrl))
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("{\"name\":\"David\"}"))
            .build();
```